# Visio 2013 - How to make custom line pattern with an existing stencil

Tags: line, visio

I'm making a custom line, but I want to use a stencil that I've already created. I have already read how to create a new line pattern with the Drawing Explorer and I understand that process just fine; however, I can't figure out how to make a new line pattern and just have it use a stencil I've already created. It would take a lot of time to recreate the stencil from scratch as it seems it wants me to do. Google has let me down on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you drag/drop or copy a shape from an existing document into a new document Visio will also copy across any associated styles at the same time.  The same goes for masters - copy a master from one stencil to another and you'll bring the style with you.

If you don't have a master, then just create a temporary one from your shape with the applied style and then delete the master once you've copied it into your target stencil - the style should remain and be availble for other shapes.